# php to set order of preference of an Array Sequence using string length

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

```
$records = array(
 '123PP' => 3.63,
 '123DDD' => 9.63,
 '123D' => 6.63,
 '123PPPP' => 9.63,
 '123DD' => 9.63,
 '123P' => 2.63,
 '123PPP' => 1.53
);
```

After looping through the records, I have to get only one value 
whose key should be `123D` because the order of preference is:
`123D`, `123P`, `123DD`, `123PP`, `123DDD`, `123PPP`, `123PPPP`...

For e.g.:

- If `123D` is not found in the array, then `123P` is the answer.
- If `123P` is not found in the array, then `123DD` is the answer.

And I have found a solution :

```
foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
if (empty($this->minLength)) {
$this->invoiceTax = $value;
          $this->minLength = strlen($key);
        }
        elseif (strpos($key, 'P') !== false && (strlen($key) < $this->minLength)) {
          $this->invoiceTax = $value;
          $this->minLength = strlen($key);
        }
        elseif (strpos($key, 'D') !== false && (strlen($key) <= $this->minLength)) {
          $this->invoiceTax = $value;
          $this->minLength = strlen($key);
        }
```

But I want to know if this code can be optimised by **not storing** the string length of every key.

Comment: use select then ctrl+k instead br for code block

Answer (score 0):

This function could easily be tidied but this is something that could be solved with recursion. This means that if `123D` is in the array the code will be highly optimised and only run once, twice for `123P`, three times for `123DD`, etc.

```
function GetMostPref($records, $key = "123", $next = "D", $depth = 0)
{
   if($depth == count($records))
   {
       // Hit end of array with nothing found
       return false;
   }

   if(strpos($next, 'D') !== false)
   {
     // Currently looking at a 'D...' key.
     // Next key is the same length as this key just with Ps.
     $nextKey = str_repeat('P', strlen($next));
   }
   else if(strpos($next, 'P') !== false)
   {
     // Currently looking at a 'P...' key.
     // Next key has one extra char and is all Ds.
     $nextKey = str_repeat('D', strlen($next)+1);
   }
   else
   {
       // Key not valid
       return false;
   }

   if(array_key_exists($key.$next, $records))
   {
      // Found the key in the array so return it.
      return $records[$key.$next];
   }
   else
   {
      // Recursive call with the next key and increased depth.
      return GetMostPref($records, $key, $nextKey, $depth + 1);
   }
}


// Testing
$records = array(
 '123PP' => 3.63,
 '123DDD' => 9.63,
 '123D' => 6.63,
 '123PPPP' => 9.63,
 '123DD' => 9.63,
 '123P' => 2.63,
 '123PPP' => 1.53
);

// Finds 123D and returns 6.63
echo GetMostPref($records);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But let me explain the case in detail. $records is a multidimensional one in which $records[$i][123P] has the value 2.63, where $i can be in range 0 - 100. So, I think passing the whole array and array_key_exists can't help.

Comment: Should still be possible, just need to rework the code so that it points at the right part of `$records`. You could use a pointer for `$records` if you're worried about passing it around too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
function prepareFunctionCall(){
  $records = array('123PP' => 3.63,'123DDD' => 9.63,'123PPPP' => 9.63
  ,'123DD' => 9.63,'123P' => 2.63,'123PPP' => 1.53); 

  // '123D' => 6.63,
  foreach($records as $key=>$value){
    $tmp = strlen($key).$key;
    $arTmp[$tmp] = $value;
  }
  getFirstValue($arTmp);
}

function getFirstValue($pArray){
  ksort($pArray);
  reset($pArray);
  print key($pArray).' = '.current($pArray);
}
```

This is an alternative for the good solution provided by MatthewMcGovern.

I provide the alternative, because this function makes use of the php functions ksort, reset and current. Those functions are created for this type of situation and if possible then would I advise you to rewrite the keys of the array before finding out which key is the first key to select. That is what I did with the addition of the strlen. But that is suboptimal compared to rewriting the keys at the moment of collecting the data. The core of the function are the calls to the functions ksort, reset and current.